# jQuery on document ready ajax inserts html, html immediately disappears

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ckeditor

The idea is to loop through the divs in the body, divs with class "editable" then have a script insert html from corresponding id in the database.(later, will implement sending changes.)  There appears to be a timing snag in inserting the html though.

The footer has two scripts.  The first modifies this div to become an inline editable area if admin is logged in. (using CKeditor)

The second script is this on document ready script, it pulls the div's html content from the database.   It fires regardless of logged in status.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".editable").each(function(){

            var div = $(this).attr('id');
            var divstring = "#" + div;

        $.post("getdbhtml.php", 
                {
                id:div
               }).done(function( html ) {
        $(divstring).html(html);

                });
        });
    });

    </script>
```

and this is the simple getdbhtml.php doc that returns the div's content

```
    $id = $_POST['id'];


    $query = "select * from edit where div_id='$id' limit 1";

    $result = $db->doQuery($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

        $content = $row->content;   
    }

     echo $content;
```

What happens is the page loads, the inserted html content flickers in and then out.  About every tenth page load it actually sticks.
My hunch is perhaps the ckeditor is still generating itself when the second script fires, but I tried to fix that by making it "on document ready".  However it still flickers out even when admin is not logged in, in other words when ckeditor is not triggered. 
 It would be silly to put a time delay on the second script.  I also tried doing the second script as an extension of the first, .done(html {});.  I also tried doing this with the regular $.ajax() call instead of specialized post, but it behaves the same.

Any ideas why it does this, or how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

The webpage is pretty simple, the target div is this:

```
<div id="inner" style="padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0;">
                <div contenteditable="true" id="editor1" class="editable" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        </div>    
 </div>
```

In chrome debugger, the ckeditor does add a considerable amount to the classes on #editor1

```
    <div contenteditable="true" id="editor1" class="editable cke_editable cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; position: relative;" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_44"></div>
```

The code being inserted right now has no html characters yet, I just want to get the insert working before correcting any html tag problems.
It goes something like "Now's your chance to register for XYZ." without quotes.

Comment: Could you post your html? And maybe a sample of the content that's going to be inserted in the `div`s? I don't know if it's going to help but maybe we can spot something there.

Comment: Ok, I've got that added.  Not sure if you wanted to see any other html parts

Comment: The part that is not working is inserting the content of the divs from the database. This has, in principle, nothing to do with the fact that the divs are editable or that you have an editor in place. So I suggest leaving out all that has to do with the "editable" part of the functionality, then see if something changes. [Tricks for trimming](http://sscce.org/#trim)

Comment: Hmm, okay, using this here's what I found.  By commenting out ckeditor scripts, the page loads the database content faithfully.  The problem seems to be the ckeditor script that was in the header (moved it to footer just to be safe.)  It's the .js that builds the ckeditor library though, the script that was already in the footer generates the instance using that library.  Hope I used the right terminology.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, and this is basically how the footer is laid out

First the library script

```
<script src="path/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The two ckeditor scripts didn't play all that nicely so I surrounded the instance script in a document.ready

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    ...ckeditor instance...
   });
   </script>
```

And the ajax database content script had a document.ready with a slight delay added to the end:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   });
   setTimeout(
        function()
        {  
                  $(".editable").each(function(){

                      var div = $(this).attr('id');
                      var divstring = "#" + div;

                  $.post("getdbhtml.php", 
                          {
                          id:div
                         }).done(function( html ) {
                  $(divstring).html(html);

                          });
                  });

                }, 100);
   </script>
```

It was already catching a couple times, so a little 100 delay seems to solve the timing issue.  It's hardly perceptible and fine for this editing purpose.

The reason I think this happens is because the ckeditor instance ends up modifying the div, including the div contents getting truncated/modified somehow (it default adds p tags, though I turned it off.)  So it is possible it was overwriting the contents after ajax already fired (even though they were ordered in completion order).